# Who creates /etc/{group,gshadow,passwd,shadow}-?

Tags: linux, files, etc

In any linux system I have access to (a couple of Archlinuxes, an Ubuntu, a Debian Sid and a Gentoo) there are the following 4 files in `/etc/`, all ending with a dash:

```
/etc/group-
/etc/gshadow-
/etc/passwd-
/etc/shadow-
```

On the internet they say that these are just backup files, updated to the next to last change.

Now I'm wondering: who's creating those files? Is it my editor? Is it the application editing those files (gpasswd, useradd, groupadd and so on)? Is it something at a lower level (maybe even a kernel module)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The backup files are created by the program that modifies your `/etc/group` or `/etc/passwd` files like `useradd`, `groupadd` and the like created as a safety precaution in case files get corrupted during edit.  Kernel never touches those files.

Comment: It's strange, because `shadow` and `gshadow` files (with a dash), have different *chmod*, unlike `000` and can be read by other users? Is there a way to make backups with proper *chmod* keeping `000`?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev As far as I know the `shadow` and `gshadow` files have permissions of `0400`.

Comment: No, on CentOS, Fedora/RedHat it's set to `0000`. It's insecure to have it set to `0400`, I believe because any user on your system could run `cat /etc/shadow` and get the output of it?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev First off I am looking at permissions on `/etc/shadow` on a RedHat system and if it actually is possible for non-root to view this file with permissions of `0400` it means that there a significant bug in permission processing unless the file is owned by some other user.

Comment: I think it's the right way to keep this file chmod `0000`. I don't think this is a bug but intended as some system files must be read by other users?

Comment: Not sure I follow your last comment.  Is this a question or a statement?

Comment: It's not very certain statement! :) I believe that this can't be a bug!

Comment: I still don't understand why backup files created with different permissions and what programs do that? I will have to investigate this!

Comment: It doesn't really matter if they have different permissions for the owner, since they are both owned by root, and root can override them easily.

Comment: Related @IliaRostovtsev: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/549464/135943