# Difference between passwd and passwd- file

Tags: users, password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who creates /etc/{group,gshadow,passwd,shadow}-?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27717/who-creates-etc-group-gshadow-passwd-shadow)

I have a strange `passwd-` file in `/etc`, notice the trailing dash:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls /etc/passw*
/etc/passwd  /etc/passwd-
```

Notice the different permissions:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -hl /etc/passw*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.0K Oct 26 13:38 /etc/passwd
-rw------- 1 root root 1.9K Oct 26 13:38 /etc/passwd-
```

and the difference in content:

```
root@ubuntu:~# diff /etc/passwd{,-}
39c39
< mysql:x:119:129:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
---
> mysql:x:119:129::/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

What's happening here?

```
root@ubuntu:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-29-generic-pae #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:25:43 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`/etc/passwd-` is a backup of `/etc/passwd` maintained by some tools, see the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/passwd.5.html). There's also a `/etc/shadow-` usually, for the same purpose.

So, by observing the output of the command `diff /etc/passwd{,-}` in your question, nothing seems fishy. Someone (or something) changed the name of your `mysql` user.