# /etc/shadow permissions security best practice (000 vs. 600 vs. 640)

Tags: files, permissions, root

We have an automated baseline check that raises an alert if the permissions on `/etc/shadow` aren’t set to 000.

The staff who receive these alerts have started to question the sanity of 000, since root can read and write wherever it wants to (all files are automatically at least 600 for root) but root can’t execute a file without execute permission set (no automatic 700 file permission for root).

Setting `/etc/shadow` permissions to 000 is in a number of baselines, e.g. the Ansible playbooks in the official Red Hat GitHub repository (for PCI DSS, CJIS, NIST, CCE).

Is there an origin story behind why `/etc/shadow` should be 000 and not e.g. the seemingly functionality identical 600? Or are my assumptions wrong about how restrictive / permissive Linux is for the root user?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The idea behind setting `/etc/shadow` permissions to 000 is to protect that file from being accessed by daemons, even when running as root, by ensuring that access is controlled by the `DAC_OVERRIDE` [capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). Since Fedora 12 and RHEL 6, Fedora-based systems run daemons without `DAC_OVERRIDE`, but grant `DAC_OVERRIDE` to administrator login sessions (so that the change is invisible to administrators).

See [lower process capabilities](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/LowerProcessCapabilities) for details.

This relies on the fact that 600 and 000 permissions aren’t functionally identical: 600 grants read-write to the file owner, whereas 000 only grants access to processes with the `DAC_OVERRIDE` capability. Traditionally, running as root always granted `DAC_OVERRIDE`, but that doesn’t have to be the case.

(SELinux can also be used to limit root’s abilities, but that’s not what’s involved here. `/etc/shadow` does have its own SELinux context, providing additional access controls.)

Comment: A process with UID 0 could still `chmod` the file even without caps and then read/write to it, so setting the permissions to 000 doesn't really protect against arbitrary command execution, right?

Comment: @ilkkachu true, and I don’t think arbitrary command execution is within the scope of the feature. The idea is to reduce the potential for privilege escalation; compromising a reduced-capability daemon won’t get you very far if it doesn’t also have a gadget to run `chmod` for you. (I haven’t checked what the SELinux context is used for, that might be relevant for `chmod`...)

Comment: See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=517575#c3 for another take on the merits or otherwise of this approach.

Comment: What is the reasonable scenario where you'd want to run a daemon without `DAC_OVERRIDE` but with root? It seems you should just get rid of it having root entirely already.

Comment: @R.. if you need other capabilities. For example `dhclient` needs `NET_ADMIN`, `NET_RAW`, and `NET_BIND_SERVICE`; in Fedora [it drops everything but those](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=357550), but to be able to do so it needs to have them to start with, which in 2009 (when the `/etc/shadow` change was made) meant running as root. Nowadays (since version 4.3 of the kernel) you could have a launcher which would set up ambient capabilities for a non-root daemon.

Comment: (As a general comment, the purpose of my answer is to explain why `/etc/shadow` is 000. I’m not commenting on whether the approach which led to that state of things is good or bad, or the best approach, or whether it was in 2009.)

Comment: @StephenKitt: In that case it should drop root too, just keeping the few caps it wants. Or ignore caps and privsep into two processes where the privileged one has no attack surface left.